# Bootstrap - How to move styles in HTML to the .css from the example

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[The example I am currently trying to reproduce.](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/examples/carousel.html)

Within the  of the carosel.html I can only presume that it has added/edited the styles which are needed to make the correct layout.

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Carousel Template &middot; Bootstrap</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<!-- Le styles -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
<style>

/* GLOBAL STYLES
-------------------------------------------------- */
/* Padding below the footer and lighter body text */

body {
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  color: #5a5a5a;
}



/* CUSTOMIZE THE NAVBAR
-------------------------------------------------- */

/* Special class on .container surrounding .navbar, used for positioning it into place. */
.navbar-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: -90px; /* Negative margin to pull up carousel. 90px is roughly margins and height of navbar. */
}
.navbar-wrapper .navbar {

}

/* Remove border and change up box shadow for more contrast */
.navbar .navbar-inner {
  border: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.25);
     -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.25);
          box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.25);
}

/* Downsize the brand/project name a bit */
.navbar .brand {
  padding: 14px 20px 16px; /* Increase vertical padding to match navbar links */
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

/* Navbar links: increase padding for taller navbar */
.navbar .nav > li > a {
  padding: 15px 20px;
}

/* Offset the responsive button for proper vertical alignment */
.navbar .btn-navbar {
  margin-top: 10px;
}



/* CUSTOMIZE THE CAROUSEL
-------------------------------------------------- */

/* Carousel base class */
.carousel {
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}

.carousel .container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9;
}

.carousel-control {
  height: 80px;
  margin-top: 0;
  font-size: 120px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}

.carousel .item {
  height: 500px;
}
.carousel img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}

.carousel-caption {
  background-color: transparent;
  position: static;
  max-width: 550px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  margin-top: 200px;
}
.carousel-caption h1,
.carousel-caption .lead {
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1.25;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}
.carousel-caption .btn {
  margin-top: 10px;
}



/* MARKETING CONTENT
-------------------------------------------------- */

/* Center align the text within the three columns below the carousel */
.marketing .span4 {
  text-align: center;
}
.marketing h2 {
  font-weight: normal;
}
.marketing .span4 p {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}


/* Featurettes
------------------------- */

.featurette-divider {
  margin: 80px 0; /* Space out the Bootstrap <hr> more */
}
.featurette {
  padding-top: 120px; /* Vertically center images part 1: add padding above and below text. */
  overflow: hidden; /* Vertically center images part 2: clear their floats. */
}
.featurette-image {
  margin-top: -120px; /* Vertically center images part 3: negative margin up the image the same amount of the padding to center it. */
}

/* Give some space on the sides of the floated elements so text doesn't run right into it. */
.featurette-image.pull-left {
  margin-right: 40px;
}
.featurette-image.pull-right {
  margin-left: 40px;
}

/* Thin out the marketing headings */
.featurette-heading {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
}



/* RESPONSIVE CSS
-------------------------------------------------- */

@media (max-width: 979px) {

  .container.navbar-wrapper {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    width: auto;
  }
  .navbar-inner {
    border-radius: 0;
    margin: -20px 0;
  }

  .carousel .item {
    height: 500px;
  }
  .carousel img {
    width: auto;
    height: 500px;
  }

  .featurette {
    height: auto;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .featurette-image.pull-left,
  .featurette-image.pull-right {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    max-width: 40%;
    margin: 0 auto 20px;
  }
}


@media (max-width: 767px) {

  .navbar-inner {
    margin: -20px;
  }

  .carousel {
    margin-left: -20px;
    margin-right: -20px;
  }
  .carousel .container {

  }
  .carousel .item {
    height: 300px;
  }
  .carousel img {
    height: 300px;
  }
  .carousel-caption {
    width: 65%;
    padding: 0 70px;
    margin-top: 100px;
  }
  .carousel-caption h1 {
    font-size: 30px;
  }
  .carousel-caption .lead,
  .carousel-caption .btn {
    font-size: 18px;
  }

  .marketing .span4 + .span4 {
    margin-top: 40px;
  }

  .featurette-heading {
    font-size: 30px;
  }
  .featurette .lead {
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 1.5;
  }

}
</style>

<!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="../assets/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<!-- Fav and touch icons -->
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="../assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-144-precomposed.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="../assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-114-precomposed.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="../assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-72-precomposed.png">
                <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="../assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-57-precomposed.png">
                               <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../assets/ico/favicon.png">
```

**Question - I would like to be able to move these styles into the actual bootsstrap.css**

I am relatively new to html . I understand that I should just copy paste them into the corresponding style on the css such as move body into body. Although this works sometimes when i try and do this for all of them It just screws up the website.

**Side question** - Would it be worth it just to leave them in the "< head >"? is this how you are meant to take from a example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do, ideally, is to take everything you have between your `<style>` tags, and move it to its own file, such as `myStyles.css`. Then, simply add a link to that file in place of your `<style>` tags

```
<link href="css/myStyles.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: I'll ask here as that other guy is not replying, Just one thing. When i do this the layout is correct but i lose the text inside each picture, how come?

Comment: It's hard to diagnose without looking at a live example... assuming you're talking about the carousel images - are the images displaying overtop of the text, since you style them as `position: absolute`? If that's the case, it should be a simple z-index issue that you can fix by adjusting the z-index of the image itself down.

Comment: Here's a live example, I've been messing with it on chrome and it's sorting of coming together but not really haha. http://profile.duhuh.co.uk/

Comment: I found if i removed the position absolute it moves into view although it's not really how it's supposed to be.

Comment: Your problem is that your `<div class="container">` is `position: relative`. Then, you set the only element inside it as `position: absolute`. By setting `position` to be `absolute` you remove that div from the layout, which makes the `container` div have height 0. If you remove the `position: relative` from the `container`, then the captions show up on the bottom left, as they are now positioned against the `item` div, your slide.

Comment: As an aside, you have a typo in your meta viewport tag - `initia-scale=1.0` should be `initial-scale=1.0`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31046/discussion-between-jack-and-grandivory)

Answer (score 1):

If you're new to this kind of stuff, i'm going to advise you not to change **bootstrap.css** or **bootstrap-responsive.css** files. Instead you could create your personal stylesheet file, let's say, **styles.css**, put it in the **css** folder and cut/paste everything inside the `<style> ... </style>` tags of that html file (not the style tag itself). Then you can just add the following line:

```
<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

to link both files together

Comment: Just one thing. When i do this the layout is correct but i loose the text inside each picture, how come?

Comment: Did you copy/paste the entire thing? If it's working in a way, it should be working the other way around too. Keep an eye open for typos like `carousel-caption{...}` instead of `.carousel-caption{...}`